# Weitzenböck identity for $TM$-valued differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, curvature, laplacian

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $\nabla$ denote its Levi-Civita connection. We have two second order differential operators $\Gamma(T^*M \otimes TM) \to \Gamma(T^*M \otimes TM)$:

The Bochner Laplacian $\Delta_B=\nabla^* \nabla$, and the "Hodge" Laplacian $\Delta_H=\delta_{\nabla} d_{\nabla}+d_{\nabla}\delta_{\nabla}$, where here $d_{\nabla}: \Omega^1(M,TM) \to \Omega^2(M,TM)$ is the covariant exterior derivative associated with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, and $\delta_{\nabla}$ is its adjoint.

> Is there some kind of Weitzenböck formula connecting these two Laplacians? something like $\Delta_H-\Delta_B=C(R^{\nabla})$, where $R^{\nabla}$ is the curvature tensor of $\nabla$?

I know that for *real-valued* one-forms, the classical Weitzenböck formula is $\Delta_H-\Delta_B=\text{Ric}$, where "$\text{Ric}$" denotes the Ricci curvature of the manifold. Can we do something similar here?

Comment: Please look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019269/2002) question and the discussion in the comments there. In particular, please pay attention to P.Peterson's [note](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/BLWformulas.pdf) where this topic is covered in a greater generality.

Comment: A proof of a similar identity for the case of vector-bundle-valued 1-forms one can find on p.18 of my [thesis](https://researchspace.auckland.ac.nz/handle/2292/22320). Perhaps, specializing that calculation for the case of $TM$-valued 1-forms would be a partial answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.